# How can I return an eloquent relationship but only select columns that are not null?

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, isnull

So I have the relationship where a client is attached to a single quote and a client has a single set of Measurements (but I called it measurement, sorry slightly confusing but it works).  So if I bind the `$quote` to my route and do `return $quote->client-measurement;` I get the following:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "client_id": 5,
    "eaves": "101.15",
    "ridges": "50.57",
    "hips": null,
    "valleys": null,
    "rakes": "95.08",
    "drip_edge": null,
    "flashing": "1.01",
    "step_flashing": null,
    "quote_id": null,
    "item_id": null,
    "created_at": "2019-01-08 17:14:43",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-08 17:14:43",
    "total_roof_area": "20.87",
    "total_steep_slope_area": "12.61",
    "total_low_slope_area": "8.27",
    "length": null,
    "width": null,
    "parapet_walls": null,
    "roof_penetrations": null,
    "total_low_slope_area_without_penetrations": null,
    "penetrations_perimeter": null,
    "roof_length": null
}
```

Is there a way I can only select those columns that are not null?  I know I can store it all then loop through it and restore values but I feel like that is super inefficient.  Any ideas?

Comment: You mean returning as API? If that so, you're looking for [eloquent-resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) plus specifically [conditional-attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `client-measurement` is an Eloquent model, you can use `filter()`:

```php
return collect($quote->client_measurement)->filter();
```

> The `filter` method filters the collection using the given callback,
>   keeping only those items that pass a given truth test.
>
> If no callback is supplied, all entries of the collection that are
>   equivalent to `false` will be removed.
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter

Comment: Never knew about filter, going to check it out ASAP.  This looks like it'll work for sure.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @travis-britz answer you can also do the following:

```
return array_filter($quote->client-measurement->toArray());
```

You can find the docs about `array_filter` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).